# PHP Query Where and Like

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-like

I try to use a system with jQuery autocomplete to provide a listview 
Here is my PHP code, except I can not find the problem, I have no error in the console but I can not seem to get the data that are in the db. It finds me no correspondence.

Conditions "where" are all right and checked (I even try the SQL query directly into phpMyAdmin, and it works, but not through the php file)

```
<?php
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=schoolby_fr', '*****', '*****');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$term = "Malrau";
$pays = "France";
$dept = "Vosges";
$tipe = "Lycée";

$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM school WHERE s_pays="'.$pays.'" AND s_dept="'.$dept.'" AND s_type="'.$tipe.'" AND s_ecole LIKE :term');
$requete->execute(array('term' => '%'.$term.'%'));

$array = array(); 

while($donnee = $requete->fetch())
{
array_push($array, $donnee['s_ecole']); 
}

echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

EDIT 22/09/2014

I wanted to show you what I get if I voluntarily recalling the condition `$pays` and `$tipe` but leaving `$term` and `$dept`.
Because it does not work with all conditions.

[image: In Phpmyadmin]

[image: Via PHP in console]

Comment: Because your MySQL return, by default, latin1-encoded records/strings when php/json expects UTF-8? Try to add `;charset=utf8` to your DSN.

Comment: you're are sooo nice, thanks it works with all conditions!! Magnifique :)

Answer (score 0):

if you simplify your prepare statement by taking out the variables and hard coding the values maybe you can identify if it's the variables

Comment: I check the variables, so they are directly noted or they are retrieved by the GET method

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare the query the right way, no need for the loop, and always turn on error mode.

```
<?php
try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=schoolby_fr', '*****', '*****');
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $term = "Malrau";
    $pays = "France";
    $dept = "Vosges";
    $tipe = "Lycée";

    $query = 'SELECT * 
              FROM school 
              WHERE s_pays= :pays
                    AND s_dept= :dept
                    AND s_type= :tipe
                    AND s_ecole LIKE :term';

    $requete = $bdd->prepare($query);
    $requete->execute(array(':pays' => $pays,
                            ':dept' => $dept,
                            ':tipe' => $tipe,
                            ':term' => '%'.$term.'%',
                      ));

    $donnees = $requete->fetchAll(); 
    //var_dump($donnees);
    echo json_encode($array);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I try it and obtain "null" values in echo.